# Protege 5.2 custom "Save as.." file format

Tags: protege, owl-api

I have implemented a custom storage renderer though owl-api 4.5.2 by extending:
**AbstractOWLStorer

OWLStorerFactoryImpl

AbstractOWLRenderer

OWLDocumentFormatFactoryImpl

PrefixDocumentFormatImpl

OWLObjectVisitor

OWLClassExpressionVisitorAdapter**

The code is working, but I would now like to make this format available through the "Save as.." dialogue in Protégé 5.2. I have successfully loaded the code through the plugin framework using the plugin example code as a guide. 
I tried hooking in the storer during a plugin tool menu initialization call

```
final OWLModelManager modelManager = getOWLModelManager();
OWLOntologyManager om = modelManager.getOWLOntologyManager();
om.getOntologyStorers().add(new mySyntaxStorerFactory());
```

This does not work as I suspect that either the manager does not persist or perhaps the Save as dialogue code has already been initialized.
Is there a better way to do this? perhaps a specific plugin type to handle this functionality? I could implement an export ontology feature through a custom tool menu item. However, I it would be much neater included on "Save as.." 
I am also planning a parser to retrieve an ontology in the custom format. Is there a recommended approach to implement this functionality via a plugin?
 Apologies if I have missed this somewhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the storing code, you need an implementation of `OWLDocumentFormat` as well; however, it's possible that the list of formats available is initialised in Protege code before you get a chance to register your format manually.

As I assume you're building your own OWLAPI jar to be deployed in Protege, check the content of the 'META-INF/services' folder - your storer should be mentioned there as the other storers are. This guarantees that the format and the storer are made available to all managers as soon as they're created.

Comment: Many thanks. I have implemented <br/>
getKey() extending PrefixDocumentFormatImpl <br/> getKey() and createFromat() extending OWLDocumentFormatFactoryImpl <br/> 
The code is included in the jar the package but not in the META-INF manifest. I'll investigate.

Comment: I am using as a starting point the maven build from the plugin examples.
I've tried adding the entry: META-INF/services/org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLStorerFactoryImpl and then inside giving the class name of my factory implementation. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The file name must not include Impl - it needs to match the name of the interface, not the implementation class. The class name only needs to appear inside the file.

Comment: Thanks. I've renamed the file based on the underlying interface org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLStorerFactory and then inside tried the implementing class name blah.blah.blah.myStorerFactory and also I tried the path /blah/blah/blah/myStorerFactory.class. In either case the named class is not instantiated during the load. Sorry, I must have missed something here.